# Change items on <select> tag after a change on input. with javascript (innerhtml) and innerhtml with php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have this part of my page.

```
the select-box ID: `GROUPS`
the input-type-number ID: `yr1`
the input-type-text ID: `yr2` (readonly)
```

[image: this]

The selectbox(GROUPS)has more options under it. It has a query that depends on a field(grpID) with prefixes of A.Y. For example:

```
20152016AA1
20152016AA2
20152016AA3
```

yeah this is quite a long kind of ID but please excuse me for that (school kind of project, so needs academic year for primary key purposes). The problem here is that when the `yr1` changes its value, I want the select box to change as well. I want it to requery like "Select * from table1 where ID like '%'.`$yr1`.`$yr2`.'%'"

yeah its a php code but I am currently under a javascript function(when yr1 changes) where I go like:
    document.getElementbyID('GROUPS').innerHTML = 'I want to echo out options under a query which will require the values of `yr` and `yr2` for sql_query correctness'

so yeah, i suppose it's gonna be AJAX but I know nothing about it. I have tried a simple tutorial but still can't get me going. Please help me people :)

Comment: You need to show some effort. There are thousands of `ajax` samples here on SO, ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php. Since you say that your have tried a simple tutorial, it would be helpful if you posted your attempt. Also, your current code is very abstract. It would be better if you posted actual html/php code, rather than images and what ever this stuff is - `the select-box ID: \`GROUPS\``